# LINQ to DataSet case insensitive group by

Tags: linq, datatable, dataset, group-by, case-insensitive

I have a data table and I want to perform a case insensitive group by over a column of data table (say `Column1` of type string). I observed that normally LINQ to DataSet performs a case sensitive comparison. For example, if `Column1` has two string values "Test" and "test", after applying `group by` it returns two separate rows with the values "Test" and "test", instead of one.

The query is:

```
var countGroupQuery = from table in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                      group table by table.Field<string>(Column1) into groupedTable
                      select new
                      {
                          value = groupedTable.Key,
                          count = groupedTable.Count()
                      };
```

Is there any method to perform a case-insensitive `group by` so that in the above example I get only one row with one value (either "Test" or "test")? `ToUpper` or `ToLower` would actually change the values to either upper case or lower case instead of using at least one of the input values, so I don't want to use this:

```
group table by table.Field<string>(Column1).ToUpper() into groupedTable
```

Comment: Your recent edits are [inappropriate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) and, given the age of the posts you're applying them to, likely spam. Please desist.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't do this from a query expression, but you can do it with dot notation:

```
var query = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                     .GroupBy(x => table.Field<string>(Column1),
                              StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                     .Select(groupedTable => new
                             {
                                 value = groupedTable.Key,
                                 count = groupedTable.Count()
                             });
```

You can even use a more complicated overload of `GroupBy` to do it in one call:

```
var query = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                     .GroupBy(x => table.Field<string>(Column1),
                              (key, group) => { value = key, 
                                                count = group.Count() },
                              StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Obviously that's using the invariant culture - you could also use the current culture or ordinal rules.

Comment: Thanx for the answer. this is what I am looking for!!!
By the way if i want to apply group by on more than one column(Column1 and Column2) then how should this query look like??

Comment: @Anoop: Grouping by more than one column *and* doing so in a case-insensitive manner will be tricky. You'd probably be best off building a custom type containing the columns you're interested in, and overriding Equals.

Comment: Jon! Can you please explain it in a little more detailed manner??

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have time at the moment. I'll try to come back to this later on.

Answer (score 3):

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bw9ksd6.aspx) has some information on datasets and case sensitivity..

> You can control the case sensitivity
>   of filtering, searching, and sorting
>   by setting the dataset's [CaseSensitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.casesensitive.aspx)
>   property.

Comment: In my case DataTable is independent of Dataset so case sensitive property is set to false. I think Linq doesnt refer to this property.It is for the operations exposed by Dataset/Datatable class.

Comment: DataTable also has the property.  But honestly I haven't used LINQ to interact with datasets/tables so I can't say whether it would actually have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = dt.AsEnumerable()
              .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Mes"))
              .Select(g => new { Mes = g.Key, 
                                 Tns = g.Sum(s => Convert.ToDecimal(s.Field<string>("Tns"))) })
              .OrderBy(g => g.Mes.First())
              .Where(g => g.Mes == ddlMes.SelectedValue.ToString());
```